# Unable to persist the selected records in a lightning:datatable using aura when the data is filtered

Tags: aura, lightning-datatable

I have a requeriment where the data is displayed in a datatable, and a input text where the user is capable of search for a string in a given column, depending on what the user type is the data that the datatable will displayed, but also the user can select the record using the checkbox feature, so Initially it the datatable display 10 records, If I select all the records works fine, but when I use the filter since the data is refreshed all the selected records lost their checked state, and viceversa If I apply the filter I select one record, and after I show all the records , that selected record lost its state. This is happening in Aura.
Is any way to solve this, I put a code in resume way:

Component:

```
  <aura:component controller="auraChooseListControllerMain" implements="force:lightningQuickAction" >
         <!--Attributes-->
        <aura:attribute name="showConfirmDialog" type="boolean" default="false"/>        
        <aura:attribute name="defaultRows" type="Set" default="[]" description="reset selected rows... antes List" />
        <aura:attribute name="selectedRecordIds" type="Set" default="{}" />
        <aura:attribute name="storedRows" type="List" default="[]" description="stored selected rows..." /> 
        <!--Searchs-->
        <aura:attribute name="searchByCID" type="String" default="" />
         <aura:attribute name="draftValues" type="Object" default="[]"/>
        <aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String" />
       
       <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" multipleRows="true">        
            <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
                <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="space" multipleRows="true">
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="searchByCID"><b>Type the asset to search:</b></label>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">
                            <lightning:input label=" " value="{!v.searchByCID}" onchange="{!c.filterByCID}"/>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                </lightning:layout>
            </lightning:layoutItem>  
        </lightning:layout>   
      
           <div class="my-stripes" >Available assets</div> 
            <lightning:card title="Lista de Activos">
              <lightning:datatable
                    aura:id="linesTable"
                    data="{!v.assets}"
                    draftValues="{!v.draftValues}"               
                    columns="{!v.columns}"
                    keyField="Id"  
                    hideCheckboxColumn="false"
                    onrowselection="{!c.handleRowSelection}"
                    onsave="{! c.handleSaveEdition }" 
                    selectedRows="{!v.defaultRows}"               
                    /> 
             </lightning:card>  
            
             <lightning:button aura:id='mainSave' label="Save" title="Submit" onclick="{!c.setFlagMain}"
                                  variant="brand" class="slds-m-top_medium"
                                  disabled="{!v.isButtonDisabled}"/> 
              <lightning:button aura:id='mainCancel' label="Cancel" title="Submit" 
              onclick="{!c.handleCancel}"  variant="brand" class="slds-m-top_medium"  />
             
        </div>  
    </aura:component>
```

Controller.js  //In handleRowSelection I tried to solve the issue but only remembers the last selection made

```
({ handleRowSelection: function(cmp,event){
        try{
        
            var selectedRows = cmp.find('linesTable').getSelectedRows();
             var selectedRecordIds = [];
             for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
                selectedRecordIds.push(selectedRows[i].Id);
            }
             cmp.set("v.defaultRows", selectedRecordIds);
            
        }catch(e){
            console.error("Error en la selección: " + e);
        }
    },
  handleSave: function(component, event, helper) {
        
        var selectedOption = component.get("v.selectedOption");
        
        helper.fetchAssetsHelper(component, event, helper,component.get("v.recordId"),selectedOption);     
    },
    filterByCID : function(component, event, helper){
         var searchString= component.get("v.searchByCID");
         var selectedOption = component.get("v.selectedOption"); 
           helper.filterByCIDHelper(component,component.get("v.recordId"),cadena,selectedOption);
        }
    }   
})
```

Helper

```
({  filterByCIDHelper : function(component, recordId,cadena1,opcion){   
      var action6 = component.get("c.filterByCIDV2");
         action6.setParams({
            "accountId": recordId,
            "cadena1": cadena1,
            "opcion": opcion
        });
        action6.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state6 = response.getState(); 
            if (state6 === "SUCCESS") {
                var records=response.getReturnValue();  
                 if (records === undefined) { 
                    var errors = response.getError();
                    if (errors) {
                        component.set("v.errorMessage", errors[0].message); 
                    }
                } else {
                    component.set("v.assets", records);
                } 
            }else{
                console.log('Error en obtener datos YYYYYY: ' + response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action6);
     }, 
       fetchAssetsHelper : function(component, event, helper,recordId,selectedOption){ 
        
             component.set('v.columns', [ 
                {label: 'Nombre', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Orden de venta', fieldName: 'OrdenVenta', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Consecutivo', fieldName: 'ConsecutivoOV', type: 'text'}     
       ]);
         
        
        var action = component.get("c.getAssets");
         action.setParams({
            "accountId": recordId,
            "opcion": selectedOption
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var resp= response.getReturnValue() 
                component.set("v.assets", resp );  
            }else{
                console.log('Error en obtener datos: ' + response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    } 
})
```

Im a little bit lost about what to do, I appreciate your valuable support.